# Domino Console port 2050 certificate expired. Can it be renewed?

Tags: certificate, console, ibm-domino

The original problem is that when you open the Domino Console app and try to connect to the server, you get "Either the server controller is not running or not listening on port 2050."  The server controller is running and is listening and accepting connections on port 2050. All the Notes.ini settings are set, etc.) Long story short, I decided to check the TLS/SSL version on port 2050 and found this:

```
issuer:     C=US,2.5.4.17=#13053031383836,ST=MA,L=Westford,O=Lotus Development Corporation,OU=Iris,CN=DominoConsole
valid from: 2001-06-18 18:27:18 UTC
valid to:   2021-06-13 18:27:18 UTC
```

June of 2021 was right about when we started having trouble and have just been limping along since.  (BTW, this is not the http/https certificate.  That cert is completely different, set to only accept TLS 1.2 and is up to date.)

Is there a way to renew or replace this certificate, or is the only option to upgrade the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well know issue and unfortunately only can be solved to update the server to 9.0.1FP6 or newer as you can read in this [knowledgebase- article](https://support.hcltechsw.com/csm?sys_kb_id=dce71d92dbd27c10cc426275ca9619fb&id=kb_article_view&sysparm_rank=1&sysparm_tsqueryId=2389f78bdbad701055f38d6d13961943&spa=1) at hcl:

> **Resolution**
> Since the certificate issued to Domino Console in Domino 9.0.1 FP6 and later releases has been valid until Feb 29 2036, it would connect to the local Domino server once upgraded to FP6.
>
> The latest FP for Domino 9.0.1 is FP10. We strongly recommend applying the latest FP/IF available for the release.